# Join List with Separator

Tags: python, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

I was implementing something similar to Python's join function, where

```
join([a1, a2, ..., aN], separator :: String)
```

returns

```
str(a1) + separator + str(a2) + separator + ... + str(aN)
```

e.g.,

```
join([1, 2, 3], '+') == '1+2+3'
```

---

I was implementing something similar and was wondering, what is a good pattern to do this? Because there is the issue of only adding the separator if it is not the last element

```
def join(l, sep):
    out_str = ''
    for i, el in enumerate(l):
        out_str += '{}{}'.format(el, sep)
    return out_str[:-len(sep)]
```

I'm quite happy with this, but is there a canoncial approach?

Comment: In Perl's `join` the separator is the first argument to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Ok in general appending N arbitrary strings iteratively would be O(N^2) in most languages and implementations, because it requires a `malloc/realloc()` call in each loop, but cPython special-cases this, so it's only N*O(1) = O(N). In native Python. string.join or sep.join are faster because they're one Python call, not N. See [Is the time-complexity of iterative string append actually O(n^2), or O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008010/is-the-time-complexity-of-iterative-string-append-actually-on2-or-on)

Comment: I like the word `delimiter` more than `separator`

Comment: @bhathiya-perera "delimiter" is broader than "separator", and is also technical jargon.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable, and so `'string a' + 'string b'` has to make a third string to combine them. Say you want to clone a string, by adding each item to the string will get \$O(n^2)\$ time, as opposed to \$O(n)\$ as you would get if it were a list.

And so, the best way to join an iterable by a separator is to use `str.join`.

```
>>> ','.join('abcdef')
'a,b,c,d,e,f'
```

---

If you want to do this manually, then I'd accept the \$O(n^2)\$ performance, and write something easy to understand. One way to do this is to take the first item, and add a separator and an item every time after, such as:

```
def join(iterator, seperator):
    it = map(str, iterator)
    seperator = str(seperator)
    string = next(it, '')
    for s in it:
        string += seperator + s
    return string
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Yeah I know about `str.join`, I was just implementing something slightly different and wondered how to do it nicely. I like your approach with using `next` at the beginning! Do you know where I can find the source of `str.join` though? Google didn't help..

Comment: @fabian789 The source for `str.join` is probably [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9873). It looks about right, and is written in C.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take that step by step:

```
def join(l, sep):
    out_str = ''
    for i, el in enumerate(l):
```

Here, why do you need the `enumerate`? You could write `for el in l:`

```
        out_str += '{}{}'.format(el, sep)
```

`.format` is not super efficient, there are other methods. You can have a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926089/python-equivalent-of-java-stringbuffer) for some researches and benchmarks on performances.

```
    return out_str[:-len(sep)]
```

This makes little sense for `l = []` if `len(sep) > 1`. `''[:-1]` is valid, and returns `''`, because python is nice, but it is not a very good way of getting around that limit case.

In general, adding something just to remove it at the end is not great.

Creating an `iter`, looking at the first value, then adding the rest, as it has been suggested in other answers, is much better.

I would also recommend writing some unit tests, so that you can then play around with the implementation, and stay confident that what you write still works.

Typically, you could write:

```
# Empty list
join([], '') == ''
# Only one element, -> no separator in output
join(['a'], '-') == 'a'
# Empty separator
join(['a', 'b'], '') == 'ab'
# "Normal" case
join(['a', 'b'], '--') == 'a--b'
# ints
join([1, 2], 0) == '102'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can go about doing this, but using an iterator can be a nice approach:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def join_l(l, sep):
    li = iter(l)
    string = str(next(li))
    for i in li:
        string += str(sep) + str(i)
    return string

print join_l(l, "-")
```

Using the first `next()` call allows you to do something different with the first item of your iterable before you loop over the rest using the `for` loop.

Comment: try it with `[]`

Answer (score -2):

As join is already a Python built in function, it is recommended not to create a function identically named. I think will be a good idea to rename your function to exclude possible conflicts.

Comment: This is just false, `help(join)` results in `NameError: name 'join' is not defined`. Now `help(str.join)` exists, but that's not  going to cause any conflicts.

Comment: "_As join is already a Python built in function, it is recommended not to create a function identically named_" - this also doesn't apply in the context of what OP asked. That's why they added the "reinventing-the-wheel" tag in the first place :)